# How can I prove that $y=m_1x+c_1$ and $y=m_2x+c_2$ are perpendicular lines?

Tags: geometry

How can I prove that $y=m_1x+c_1$ and $y=m_2x+c_2$ are perpendicular lines?

It is also given that $m_1m_2=-1$.

So far i got to the point that $y/x1 -c1=m1$ and $y/x2-c2=m2$ is this the right way to start? Or should i solve it simultanously? I really have no idea how to solve this, that's why I didn't add anything else, sorry.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possibly helpful: [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordperpendicular.html).

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this exercise is a bit artificial since you have to prove something you assume to be true (I mean, do you know why two lines are perpendicular if the product of their respective slopes is $-1$?). This explanation uses a little bit of trigonometry, so if you haven't learnt it yet, skip this answer.

If you know that the slope of a line is determined by the angle formed between the line and the $x$-axis, as represented in the following graph:

[image]

You can deduce that two lines are perpendicular if you know a little bit of trigonometry. Actually, the slope of line is equal to the tangent of the angle formed between the line and the $x$-axis. The angle is taken going from the $x$-axis to the line counter-clockwise as presented above. The blue line is a line with such an angle equal to $\alpha$ and going from some point of coordinates $(a,b)$. Hence, its equation is $\color{blue}{d_{1}\equiv y=\tan(\alpha)(x-a)+b}$. In the sequel, we suppose that $\color{blue}{d_{1}}$ is not parallel or perpendicular to the $x$-axis, i.e. $\alpha\neq k\pi$ and $\alpha\neq (\pi/2)+k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Now, consider a perpendicular line $d_{2}\equiv y=\tan(\beta)(x-c)+d$. Any line parallel to $d_{2}$ will have the same slope (i.e. $\tan(\beta)$) and will also be perpendicular to $d_{1}$. Now, take the parallel $\color{red}{d_{3}}$ to $d_{2}$ going through the intersection point between $\color{blue}{d_{1}}$ and the $x$-axis. You can see that the angle between $\color{red}{d_{3}}$ and the $x$-axis is equal to $\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha}$, which means that the slope of $\color{red}{d_{3}}$ is $\tan(\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha})$. As $\color{red}{d_{3}}$ is parallel to ${d_{2}}$ by construction, $d_{2}$ has the same slope, which is $\tan(\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha})$.

Now, if you know a little bit about trigonometry, $$\tan(\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha})=\frac{\sin(\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha})}{\cos(\color{red}{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}+\color{blue}{\alpha})}=\frac{\cos(-\color{blue}{\alpha})}{\sin(-\color{blue}{\alpha})}=\frac{\cos(\color{blue}{\alpha})}{-\sin(\color{blue}{\alpha})}=-\frac{1}{\tan(\color{blue}{\alpha})}$$

Which shows that the product of the respective slopes of $\color{blue}{d_{1}}$ and $d_{2}$ is indeed equal to $$\underbrace{\color{blue}{\tan(\alpha)}}_{\text{slope of } \color{blue}{d_{1}}}\cdot \underbrace{\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\alpha)}_{\text{slope of } d_{2}}=\underbrace{\color{blue}{\tan(\alpha)}}_{\text{slope of } \color{blue}{d_{1}}}\cdot \underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{\tan(\color{blue}{\alpha})}\right)}_{\text{slope of } d_{2}}=-1$$

This can be done in a more general setup if one does know the representation of line with vectors,...

Comment: You have said that 2 lines are perp if $mm'=1$. I suppose it is a typo.

Comment: @JnxF Yes, thank you, I'll correct it :)

Answer (score 0):

Two lines are perpendicular if their slopes multiply to give $-1$, as yours do.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the functions:

$$ y_1 = m_1 x + c_1 $$
$$ y_2 = m_2 x + c_2 $$
$$ m_1 m_2 = -1. $$

Solving for $m_2$ yields

$$m_2 = -\frac{1}{m_1}.$$

We plug this into the equation for $y_2$ getting

$$ y_2 = -\frac{1}{m_1} + c_2. $$

This is $y_2$ such that $y_2 \perp y_1.$